# Нужна помощь в XAML MAUI

Tags: android, xaml, maui

Я сейчас на практике и мне надо сделать анимацию для андроид на xaml, где можно найти информацию как это реализовать, я уже все переискал, но везде пишут только про WPF

Comment: Какую анимацию, чего анимацию...? Ну вот например [Lottie анимация](https://askxammy.com/lottie-animations-net_maui/), берите after effects, создавайте анимацию покадрово, встраивайте в проект, готово. Не оно? Ну, тогда наверно стоит больше информации предоставить, верно? Анимации бывают ведь разные, и все они по разному делаются, это может быть код, набор точек, анимация, гифка, apng в конце концов. Если речь про анимацию свойство, то в MAUI это кастрировано и вам надо писать [свое поведение](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75949111)  (или качать готовое).

Comment: Мне нужно что бы объект, который взят как картинка, двигался по заданому мной маршруту

Comment: Мне еще нужно понять как писать анимацию на с# что бы он взаимодействовал с xaml, но в интернете есть информация как это делать в WPF. то есть для виндовс,для андроид не могу найти, может вы знаете где найти эту информацию?